# How to use JSON data in JS function?

Tags: javascript, json

I am pulling out data from bitcoinaverage.com's API and saving it in var 'price'.

Later I want to use it in a calculation im doing in JS but it doesn't work, **only works if I put a static integer instead of dynamic 'price'**.

I've tried pasteInt() on price and it still doesn't work. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/7b2jaLxh/

```
var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
xbtc.open('GET', 'https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/CAD/', true);
xbtc.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xbtc.readyState == 4){
        var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
        price = ticker.last;
    }
};
xbtc.send();
```

here's the JS where im using price variable: (at the bottom)

```
var directionSlider = document.getElementById('slider-direction');

noUiSlider.create(directionSlider, {
    start: 20,
    connect: [true, false],
    direction: 'ltr',
    range: {
        'min': 2,
        'max': 99.99
    }
});
var cadc = document.getElementById('cadc');
var btcc = document.getElementById('btcc');

directionSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    cadc.value = directionSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    cadConvert();
});

cadc.addEventListener('change', function(){
    directionSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
    cadConvert();
});
btcc.addEventListener('change', function(e){
   directionSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value*price);
});
function cadConvert() {
    var cad = directionSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    var cadCalc = cad / price;
    document.getElementById("btcc").value = cadCalc;

}
```

Comment: where is price being initially declared? It seems like you are probably trying to use `price` outside of its scope

Comment: I've saved it in a file named price.js  but I called <script src="js/price.js"></script> in the html where I run the js.

Comment: Can you tell us what the value of price is in your cadConvert() function? Set a breakpoint or do a console.log.

Comment: 1308.74 CAD, I output it like this:
document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = price + " CAD";
and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `cad` variable assignment to this:

`var cad = parseFloat(directionSlider.noUiSlider.get());`

That's because the slider is most likely returning the value as a string, rather than as a floating-point number.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I did a `console.log(cad, typeof cad);` and it was indeed a string value that's being returned from your slider, so I changed the code to the following:

```
function cadConvert() {
    if(!price) return;
    var cad = parseFloat(directionSlider.noUiSlider.get());
    var cadCalc = cad / price;
    document.getElementById("btcc").value = cadCalc;
}
```

I tested, and your slider is working fine now. Try this updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5pxvvmdL/

Also, I added a `var price;` declaration at the top near your other declarations, just for code readability purposes, as even though when you assign a variable in Javascript without using `var` it automatically gets declared as a global variable, it's best if you explicitly do that in your code by declaring your global variable literrally using `var` in the global scope (outside of any functions). As mentioned, just for code readability purposes.

Additonally, I commented out the `document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "Global Market: $" + (price).toFixed(2) + " CAD";` line in price.js as there's no "btc" layer in the document and thus it was throwing an error.

Finally, I added a call to cadConvert() on the onreadystatechange event so that the default Bitcoin price is displayed as soon as it's loaded, using the default slider price.

Comment: Try adding this code right after `cadConvert(){` so you can see exactly what values and of which types are being received:

`console.info('cad: ', cad, (typeof cad));`
`console.info('price: ', price, (typeof price));`

Then paste here in a comment the output so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You saved the day ablopez!  Thank you so much.